# How to insert an image into an SQLite Data Base in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, sqlite

at first I want to say that I am quite new to Android Studio, so this might be a question about basic stuff.

I am currently programming a quiz app for Android now and I want to store all the questions into a SQLite database.

```java
SQLiteDatabase gdb = openOrCreateDatabase(gdbName, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
 gdb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + gdbTabelle + "(id INTEGER, question TEXT, image INTEGER, rightAnswer TEXT, alreadyAnswered INTEGER)");
gdb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + gdbTabelle + " VALUES(1, 'When did Germany reunify', R.drawable.wvg, '03.10.1990', '0')");
gdb.close();
```

As you can see, I thought that I could access the image, which will be displayed in the app over the question, via its ID (therefore I wrote R.drawable.wvg, wvg is the name of the image, I want to use. I stored it in the res/drawable folder.)
When I wrote

```java
imField.setImageResource(cursor.getInt(2));
```

So I tried

```java
imField.setImageResource(2131165395);
```

(this number is the ID of the picture, I got it through debugging), it worked perfectly. Therefore I thought I could handle it like:

```java
SQLiteDatabase gdb = openOrCreateDatabase(gdbName, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
 gdb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + gdbTabelle + "(id INTEGER, question TEXT, image INTEGER, rightAnswer TEXT, alreadyAnswered INTEGER)");
gdb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + gdbTabelle + " VALUES(1, 'When did Germany reunify', 2131165395, '03.10.1990', '0')");
gdb.close();
```

but when I then tried

```java
imField.setImageResource(cursor.getInt(2));
```

(I tried this with and without quotation marks, it failed both times, the image did not get displayed).

My last approach was something like

```java
int a = cursor.getInt(2);
imField.setImageResource(cursor.getInt(2));
```

, which was not successful either.

So is there an elegant way to store an image in a SQLite database?

Comment: Do **not** store resource identifiers in a database. Those values can change from build to build of your app.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, that was my thought too...

Comment: "So is there an elegant way to store an image in a SQLite database?" -- assuming that the image in question always comes from a resource, hold onto some string or other number that you can use in code to map to the proper resource identifier (e.g., via a `HashMap`).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would recommend using [Jetpack Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room).
It has better error verification and it is easier to use.

Secondly, you have multiple problems here:

1. You are attempting to insert the image id as a string, not as an integer. Instead of this:

   ```
   gdb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + gdbTabelle + " VALUES(1, 'When did Germany reunify', R.drawable.wvg, '03.10.1990', '0')");
   ```

   The insert should look like this:

   ```
   gdb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + gdbTabelle + " VALUES(1, 'When did Germany reunify'," + R.drawable.wvg + ", '03.10.1990', '0')");
   ```
2. This code is correct and should have worked:

   ```
   gdb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + gdbTabelle + " VALUES(1, 'When did Germany reunify', 2131165395, '03.10.1990', '0')");
   ```

   But I guess what happened is that you wrote multiple rows with the same row id and the wrong image resource id while debugging. And then you only read the first wrong row. Try clearing app data in settings or completely reinstalling it or deleting excess rows using execSQL or specifying your id as the primary key (that way the id will always be unique and result in row overwriting).

Also, I would suggest creating a separate class for work with DB by extending SQLiteOpenHelper, you can read android docs about that (https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite). And for reading column values it is better to use getInt with [getColumnIndex](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor#getColumnIndex(java.lang.String)) and with column names stored in constants. It would decrease the chance of accident mistakes and make code more readable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Regarding 2., I have to say, that this is my only row...

Comment: In that case, you should log or check in the debugger what value cursor.getInt(2); is really returning.